# cannot run jconsole

Tags: memory-leaks

In my windows XP machine I try to run jconsole like this:

```
jconsole 2228
```

Here 2228 is the pid of the process(got it from Task Manager).
The output is:

```
Unable to attach to 2228: Could not map vmid to user name
```

My java version is 1.5.0_07
Also tried

> jps -mlv

.
Output is empty.In tmp folder there is no hsperfdata_.
Tried the same thing in a linux box with same result.In the linux box I logged in as root.Output of the id command:

```
# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),1(bin),2(daemon),3(sys),4(adm),6(disk),10(wheel)
```

Output of jps command:

```
jps -mlv
28574 sun.tools.jps.Jps -mlv -Dapplication.home=/usr/local/Java/jdk1.5.0_16 -Xms8m
```

One difference with windows box is atleast /tmp/hsperfdata_root exists and permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     root      4096 Dec 17 12:52 hsperfdata_root
```

Plz help.
Regards,
Subhendu

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to connect using the PID on windows, the TEMP directory for both the user running jconsole and the user running the jvm need to be the same.  If jps doesn't list your jvm, then this is the problem.

This usually occurs with JVMs which are run as windows services that run as SYSTEM user.  The temp directory for SYSTEM user is usually C:\windows\temp.  The temp directory for you is probably C:\Documents and Setting\YOURNAME...

Comment: Great! to complement your answer, this environment variable needs to be set:

`TMP=/C/Users/{USERNAME}/AppData/Local/Temp`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found out that adding system property com.sun.management.jmxremote solves the problem.
However, if someone wants to add anything to enhance my understanding - most welcome.

Regards,

Subhendu